# how do i can swich the view based on the logged in user in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I need to either redirect user or show not authorized page according to usertype of the logged in user.

Here is some which would give you an idea.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["isadmin"].Value != "true")
        return View("NotAuthorized","Index");
    else
        return View();
}
```

Here I have created new view with NotAuthorized as view name and projectname.Models.NotAuthorized as strongly type view.

after building and running the project,it give me following error.

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES :-)

I got it, here is solution.

```
if (Request.Cookies["isadmin"].Value != "true")
    //return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized", "Users");
    //return View("NotAuthorized");
else
    return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the final version? Did you created the project using the VS template? Also, check your project references.

Comment: Yes, I am using final version and not using any VS templates